# Angular query (get) TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a query that displays a detailed view of a product catalog.

This is my service:

```
factory('ProductsFactory', function($resource){
    var products = {};

    products.getProducts = function(){
      var productItems = $resource('/api/products/:productId',{
        query: {
          method:'GET',
          params:{
            productId:'productId'
          },
          isArray: true
        }
      });

      return productItems;
    }
    return products;

  });
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('ProductCtrl', function ($scope, ProductsFactory, $modal, $log, $stateParams) {
    var productItems = ProductsFactory.getProducts()
    $scope.products = productItems.query();
    $scope.selectedProduct = productItems.get({productId:1});
  });
```

The first one (productsItems.query()) returns all product. It works.

But $scope.selectedProduct, which is suppose to display a selected products does not work.

I get this error in my console:

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: have you added any angular resource library ?

Comment: By any change are you returning array for the `get({productId:1})`. Check you browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because AngularJS tries to cast an object (the result of you second query) into an array. It works when you GET all your objects, but it fails when you only GET a single object.

Comment: I've the same issue on my side. It returns an Object Object on my side. Do you know how to work around ?

Answer (score 3):

Strange, that there is still no approved answer.

As mentioned in other answers and comments, the problem is in the fact that response is object and not array (or backwards. It can be fixed by setting `isArray: false` in resource options (or `isArray: true` in opposite situation):

```
get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
```

But as you are using `$resource`, you should keep it close to REST-architecture, so `get` shouldn't return an array - there is `query` for that.